# Splunk Regex Email Expression

Tags: regex, splunk

When attempting to create e-mail alerts within our Splunk> server (Version 4.3 for those who care) we receive an e-mail invalid error message which I have traced back to the `restmap.conf` file.  The current expression is:

`validate( match('action.email.to',  "(?i)^(?:[^@\s]+@(?:[^@\s.]+\.)+[a-z]{2,})(?:\s*[,;]\s*(?:[^@\s]+@(?:[^@\s]+\.)+[a-z]{2,}))*$"), "One of the email addresses in 'action.email.to' is invalid")`

I am not good at regex at all and this one seems to be rather complex.  I want the expression to allow e-mail address such as `john.smith@abc.p1` I attempted to create or modify the current regex using `http://regex101.com/#PCRE` but this is a little over my head still.

Comment: Please see [Using a regular expression to validate an email address](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/201323/using-a-regular-expression-to-validate-an-email-address).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, the current regex is this:

```
(?i)^(?:[^@\s]+@(?:[^@\s.]+\.)+[a-z]{2,})(?:\s*[,;]\s*(?:[^@\s]+@(?:[^@\s]+\.)+[a-z]{2,}))*$
```

It is failing to match `john.smith@abc.p1` because there is a number(1) in the `.p1` part of the email.

So in your regex.., in this part: `[a-z]{2,}`.  You just need to allow for a `1` or the whole number set `0-9` like so:  `[a-z0-9]{2,}` or `[a-z1]{2,}`

So this is the your full regex, modified to work for your situation:

```
(?i)^(?:[^@\s]+@(?:[^@\s.]+\.)+[a-z0-9]{2,})(?:\s*[,;]\s*(?:[^@\s]+@(?:[^@\s]+\.)+[a-z0-9]{2,}))*$
```

Working regex example:

http://regex101.com/r/lX7yM5

Comment: Thanks look like that did it, after posting I also got a more simplex one working `^[_a-z0-9]+(\.[_a-z0-9]+)*@[a-z0-9]+(\.[a-z0-9]+)*(\.[a-z0-9]{2,4})$` which lead me to a better understanding of the syntax.